# iOS Interval Local Notification with Different Message

Tags: swift, push-notification

I want to Send a Local Notification Every Hour (for just one day) With Different Message. Also want to Dismiss the Previous Notification When New one comes.

I Used This Code But The Seccond Notification Comes with the Same Text as First One !
and Doesn't Dismiss the Previous...

```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    var Text = "!!!!!!!!!"
    let Texts = [
        "11111111111",
        "22222222222",
        "33333333333",
        "44444444444",
        "55555555555"
    ]

    Text = Texts[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Texts.count)))]



    let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    localNotification.alertBody = Text
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)


    let localNotification2:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification2.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    localNotification2.alertBody = Text
    localNotification2.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    localNotification2.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification2)
```

Comment: did you find any solution? i too facing same issue.

Comment: No my friend, sorry.

Comment: i read some of the links have you tried this : http://iphonediscoveries.blogspot.sg/2013/11/renewing-uilocalnotifications.html

Answer (score 0):

I Created a Method to Get the Text From Method Maybe Solve The Problem

```
internal func RandomText(Text: String) -> (String){

var Text = "!!!!!!!!!"
let Texts = [
    "11111111111",
    "22222222222",
    "33333333333",
    "44444444444",
    "55555555555"
]

Text = Texts[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Texts.count)))]
return(Text)
```

}

and Changed the Alert Text to :

```
localNotification2.alertBody = String(RandomText)
```

but this Always Return : (Function)